# Magento 2 migration tools DELTA?

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, delta-migration

I'm actually migrate my website from Magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.1.9. After mapping all the attributes and field, Everything works like a charm. 
Now I have a big work with my products from M1 to M2

Can I modify everything I need in M2 and run the DELTA step (without changing my `config.xml` file) to sync only new orders / customers even if my attributes / settings changed ?

Comment: Simply by reading the rest of the config.xml file !! The DELTA process update only logs, customers and sales... After many changes in settings, products and attribute, only sales / customers are added.

Comment: Does the delta step work for you? For me migrating from 1.7.0.2 -> 2.2.3 the delta command failed and ran in an unstoppable loop.

Comment: If I remember correctly (but I migrate from 1.7.0.2 to 2.1.9) the delta command is still running until you stop it and its a normal behavior. you can read this : https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/4 or this : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-delta.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify everything in Magento2. But do not create customer and order in Magento2.

Because delta process migrate data that customers added via storefront (created orders, reviews, changes in customer profiles, etc.)